# ¿Cómo hacer una restricción CHECK en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, checkmysql

BUen día, ¿podrían decirme cómo es el script para crear una restricción CHECK junto con CREATE TABLE?
Tengo un pequeño avance, pero me dice que tengo un error en la palabra reservada CHECK.

```
CREATE TABLE cliente (
    cedula integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre varchar(15),
    apellidos varchar(30),
    sexo char(1),
    telefono varchar(13),
    direccion varchar(100),
    email varchar(30),
    pais varchar(30),
    CONSTRAINT check_sexo CHECK (sexo="M", or sexo="F")
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

¿Alguien tiene una idea de qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

Para crear una restricción CHECK junto con CREATE TABLE en MariaDB, debes seguir los siguientes pasos:

1. Abre tu cliente de MariaDB o una interfaz de línea de comandos.
2. Usa el comando CREATE TABLE para crear una nueva tabla y define las columnas que deseas incluir en tu tabla junto con sus tipos de datos y restricciones. Aquí también es donde agregarás tu restricción CHECK.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que queremos crear una tabla llamada "empleados" con las columnas "id_empleado" y "salario", y queremos asegurarnos de que el salario sea mayor a 0:

```sql
CREATE TABLE empleados (
  id_empleado INT PRIMARY KEY,
  salario DECIMAL(10, 2) CHECK (salario > 0)
);
```

En este ejemplo, hemos definido la columna "salario" como DECIMAL con una precisión de 10 dígitos y una escala de 2 dígitos. También hemos agregado la restricción CHECK para asegurarnos de que el salario sea mayor a 0.

3. Ejecuta el comando CREATE TABLE para crear la tabla. Si todo va bien, se creará la tabla con la restricción CHECK especificada.

Es importante tener en cuenta que algunas versiones de MariaDB pueden no admitir restricciones CHECK. En su lugar, puedes usar disparadores (triggers) para lograr el mismo resultado.

Fuente: `https://talkai.info/es`